# Usar un botón y redireccionar a múltiples URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Actualmente estoy tratando de utilizar un `button` para redireccionar a multiples url dependiendo el valor de una variable. Por ejemplo si es 1, la url https.... si es 2 url https..... si es 3 url https....

El valor lo obtengo de un `<div>`

```
<div id="dato" name="dato"></div>
```

ejemplo del código en `js`

```
function validar_url(){
    
    var valor = $('#dato').val();
   
        if( valor == '3' ){
            location.href = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGCONv1?m=";
        }
        else if( valor == '2' ){
            location.href = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGNWINGRCH?m=";
        }
        else if( valor == '1' ){
            location.href = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGCONRCH?m=";
        }
        else{
            location.href = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGNWINGv1?m=";
        }
        return;
        //alert("Datos correctos.");
    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener el número que haya en un `input` cada vez que cambie y asignar la url a la etiqueta `<a>` en función del valor obtenido.

Si el valor lo obtienes de un `div`, debes cambiar `.val()` por `.html()`, ya que los `div` no tienen atributo `value`.

El código está comentado, si tienes dudas, deja un comentario.

```js
$('#dato').on('input', function() {
  validar_url();
});

function validar_url() {
  //Obtener el número que haya dentro del input
  let valor = $('#dato').val();
  //Declarar la variable url e inicializarla vacía
  let url = '';
  //Asignar la url en función del número recuperado del div
  if (valor == '3') {
    url = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGCONv1?m=";
  } else if (valor == '2') {
    url = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGNWINGRCH?m=";
  } else if (valor == '1') {
    url = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGCONRCH?m=";
  } else {
    url = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGNWINGv1?m=";
  }
  //Asignar la url al atributo href de la etiqueta <a>
  $("#redireccion").attr("href", url);
  //Solo para fines ilustrativos, se muestra en consola
  console.log(url);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="dato" />
<!-- dejar el botón solo con el id -->
<a id="redireccion">
  <button>Redireccionar</button>
</a>
```

**Actualización:** Basado en el comentario, te dejo una alternativa con `window.open(url, '_blank');` donde el segundo parámetro `_blank` es usado para abrir el enlace en una nueva pestaña:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  let valor = $('#dato').val();
  let url = '';
  if (valor == '3') {
    url = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGCONv1?m=";
  } else if (valor == '2') {
    url = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGNWINGRCH?m=";
  } else if (valor == '1') {
    url = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGCONRCH?m=";
  } else {
    url = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGNWINGv1?m=";
  }
  //Redireccionar de acuerdo a la url
  window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="dato" />
<div style="text-align: right;">
  <button id="btn" name="btn" type=" button">
    Estoy en huelga...
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Entiendo, tengo mis ideas mas claras solo una duda ... veo que lo estas poniendo con una etiqueta es valido si le pongo un id a mi boton y le ejecuto desde ahi ???                      Mi botón esta así mandaría a llamar el id nomas ??

Comment: <div style="text-align: right;">
<button id="btn" name="btn" type=" button" disabled="disabled">Estoy en huelga...</button>
</div>

Comment: Acabo de agregar una alternativa que ejecuta la función en el evento `click` del botón.

Comment: GRACIAS POR SUS COMENTARIOS, YA ME DIERON MUCHAS IDEAS IGUAL ANDO POR AQUI

Answer (score 2):

Creo que tienes la idea básica.

En mi ejemplo, doy al usuario la posibilidad de seleccionar su destino en un *radio button* y un par de botones, uno para *ver* el destino (lo imprimirá en la consola) y otro para ir a la dirección seleccionada.

Para lograrlo, he creado la función `getDestinoSeleccionado` que recoge el valor seleccionado por el usuario en el *radio button* y devuelve la dirección a utilizar, y luego las funciones `verClick` que imprime dicha dirección en la consola e `irClick()` que hace la redirección a la dirección seleccionada.

```js
function getDestinoSeleccionado() {
  var valor = document.querySelector('input[name="destino"]:checked').value;
  var destino = "";
  
  if (valor == 'd1' ) {
    destino = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGCONv1?m=";
  } else if (valor == 'd2') {
    destino = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGNWINGRCH?m=";
  } else if (valor == 'd3') {
    destino = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGCONRCH?m=";
  } else {
    destino = "https://gadd.upaep.mx/Forms/EXPDIGNWINGv1?m=";
  }
  return(destino);
}

function verClick() {
  var destino = getDestinoSeleccionado();
  console.log("destino:" + destino);
}

function irClick() {
  var destino = getDestinoSeleccionado();
  location.href = destino;
}
```

```html
  <p>Selecciona tu destino :</p>
  <input type="radio" id="d1" name="destino" value="d1" checked>
  <label for="d1">Destino 1</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="d2" name="destino" value="d2">
  <label for="d2">Destino 2</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="d3" name="destino" value="d3">
  <label for="d3">Destino 3</label>

  <br>  

  <button onClick="verClick()">Ver destino</button>
  <button onClick="irClick()">Ir a destino</button>
```

Pulsa el botón *"Ejecutar"* para ver el código en acción acá mismo en la respuesta.

Comment: Es una muy buena idea sin embargo el objetivo es que todo se quede en un solo botón y de acuerdo al valor que se recupere me redireccione a la URL , muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes quedarte solo con el botón que hace la redirección y eliminar el otro botón, que está puesto solo con fines educativos.